# Permissions Issue Attempting to CreateLink on a DriveItem

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the code sample below but I get an `invalidRequest` error.

The drive and driveItem Ids are correct.

I try the same using the `Microsoft Graph Explorer` and it informs that I need to consent to missing permissions. It does not indicate which permissions.

The application has `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Files.Read.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`, `Sites.Read.All` which Microsoft's documentation suggest is enough.

A web article suggested that the application also needs `Sites.Manage.All` and `Sites.FullControl.All`. However, these did not resolve the issue. An `invalidRequest` is returned:

```
2022-02-02T17:50:13 Exception: Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2022-02-02T17:50:03
    request-id: 8e6*****-****-****-****-******382c2c
    client-request-id: 8e6*****-****-****-****-******382c2c
```

Anyone know what permissions are needed or need to be consented?

```
// Create a shared link

var type = "edit"; // edit or view or embed
var scope = "organization"; // Also anonymous or organization
try
{
    var result = await graphServiceClient.Drives[documentsDrive.Id].Items[pcScheduleAssessmentsFolderForStudent.Id]
                .CreateLink(type, scope, null, null, null, null)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string errMsg = DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + " Exception: " + ex.Message;
    if(ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        errMsg += " InnerException: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
    }
    logger.LogError(errMsg);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in Microsoft Graph Explorer the `Modify permissions` tab which permissions are required to run the query and which permissions require consent of your organization's Admin.

Your permissions are correct but it looks like that one or more permissions require Admin consent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am now past the permissions problem which was a graph explorer only issue. Now, I am getting an invalid request 400 response. Any thoughts?